# Using pointers to get value from multidimensional array - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get value from "second row" in multidimensional array. But I have some problems with that.
I thought that numbers are stored sequentialy in memory so `tab[2][2]` is stored same as `tab[4]`. But it seems that I was wrong.

This is what I tried:

```
int b[2][2] = {{111,222},{333,444}};
int i = 0;
for(;i < 100; i++)
    printf("%d \n", **(b+i));
```

The problem is that I get only `111` and `333` as the result. There is no `222` or `444` in other 98 results. Why?

Comment: Yep, the double * was the issue.  Would've been fine with *(b+i).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `**(b+i)` doesn't do what you think it does.  It evaluates to:

```
b[i][0]
```

As [Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234599/using-pointers-to-get-value-from-multidimensional-array-c/23234643?noredirect=1#comment35548934_23234643),

```
**(b+i)
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(*(b+i)+0)
```

and since `*(b+i)` is equivalent to `b[i]`, the expression as a whole can be seen as:

```
*(b[i]+0)
```

and hence:

```
b[i][0]
```

Since your array has only 2 rows, only the values of `i` for 0 and 1 are in bounds of the array (that's the 111 and 333).  The rest was wildly out of bounds.

What you could do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int b[2][2] = { { 111, 222 }, { 333, 444 } };
    int *base = &b[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, base[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: 111
1: 222
2: 333
3: 444
```

Comment: Explaining a bit more, `*(a+b)` is identical to `a[b]`, and `*a` is equivalent to `*(a+0)` in the context of retrieving the stored value.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a two-dimensional array as a special form of a one-dimensional array. Your array holds 2 elements (!). (Each element happens to be an array of two elements, but let's ignore that for a sec.) Let's make the dimensions different so that we can distinguish them:

`int arr2d[2][3]` holds 2 elements (each being an array of 3 elements). The "primary index" is written first, that is if you have a one-dimensional array of 3 like `int arr1d[3]`and want to have an array of those with three elements like arr2d, you have to write `arr2d[2][3]`. You could arrange that with a typedef which makes it clear that **all arrays in C are essentially 1-dimensional:**

```
typedef int arr3IntT[3];
arr3IntT arr2d[2] = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5} };
```

Now what does `arr2d+i` mean? arr2d, like any array, decays to a pointer to its first element (which is an array of 3 ints). `arr2d+1` adds the offset of 1 of those elements to the address, so that like always the expression yields the address of the second element (which is the second array of 3 ints). Dereferencing it once like `*(arr2d+1)` yields that element, i.e. the one-dimensional sub-array of 3 ints. It decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. a pointer to the first int in that second sub-array. Dereferencing *that* in the expression `**(arr2d+1)` yields that int, like always. To summarize: In your original code you iterate from sub-array to sub-array, always referencing the first of their elements, incidentally going out of bounds for i>1.

But principally you are right, elements of n-dimensional arrays in C are lying contiguously in memory, so you can access them one by one if you like to. You just have to index a pointer to int, not one to int[3]. Here is how: The expression `arr2d` decays to a pointer to its first element which is an array of 3 ints. Dereferencing that gives that first element, a one-dimensional array of 3 ints. Like all arrays, it decays to a pointer to its first element, an int, which is the very first element in the data:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr2d[2][3] = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5} };
    int *p_el1 = *arr2d;
    int i, j;


    // Sanity check by indexing 2-dimensionally
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) for(j=0; j<3; j++) printf("%d\n", arr2d[i][j]);

    // iterate the elements 1 by 1
    for(i=0; i<3*2; i++) printf("%d\n", p_el1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A multidimensional array is not a fundamentally new type. It's an array type where the elements are themselves arrays. To quote the C99 standard §6.2.5 ¶20 (Types)

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
>   objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.
>   Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number
>   of elements in the array.

```
int b[2][2] = {{111, 222}, {333, 444}};
```

The above statement defines `b` to be an array of `2` elements where each element is the type `int[2]` - an array of `2` integers. It also initializes the array with the array initializer list. An array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in some cases.

In the `printf` call, `b` decays to a pointer to its first element. Therefore, it's equivalent to `&b[0]` and has type `int (*)[2]` - a pointer to an array of `2` integers. Please note that it's undefined behaviour to access elements out of the bound of an array. Therefore, the `for` loop condition `i < 100` is wrong. It should be `i < 2`. Now, let's try to demystify the expression `**(b+i)`.

```
b -------------> pointer to a[0]
b + i ---------> pointer to a[i]
*(b + i)  -----> a[i]
*(*(b + i)) ---> *(a[i]) ----> *(&(a[i])[0]) ----> a[i][0]
```

As noted, the elements of the array are themselves arrays. Therefore, `a[i]` is an array. Again, the array decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e., to `&(a[i])[0]`. Applying indirection operator `*` on this pointer gets us the value at that address which is `a[i][0]`.

You can access the elements of the array through a pointer but the pointer type must be a pointer to element type of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int b[2][2] = {{111, 222}, {333, 444}};
    int (*p)[2] = b;

    // (sizeof b / sizeof b[0]) evaluates to 
    // the size of the array b
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof b / sizeof b[0]); i++)
        // (sizeof *p / sizeof (*p)[0]) evaluates to
        // the size of element of the array which is
        // itself an array.
        for(int j = 0; j < (sizeof *p / sizeof (*p)[0]); j++)
            printf("%d\n", *(*(p + i) + j));

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the expression `*(*(p + i) + j)` can be decoded as

```
p  ---------------> pointer to the first element of b, i.e., &b[0]
(p + i) ----------> pointer to b[i], i.e., &b[i]
*(p + i) ---------> the array element b[i] ---> decays to &(b[i])[0]
*(p + i) + j -----> &(b[i])[j]
*(*(p + i) + j) --> the element b[i][j]
```

Therefore, the expression `*(*(p + i) + j)` is equivalent to `b[i][j]`. In fact, the C99 standard §6.5.2.1 ¶2 says -

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is
>   identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`

This means we have the following are equivalent with context to the above program -

```
*(*(p + i) + j)
// equivalent to
p[i][j]
// equivalent to
b[i][j]
// equivalent to
*(*(b + i) + j)
```